# A-frame: show a series of elements after hidding another series by clicking

Tags: visibility, aframe

I have am A-frame scene where a series of entities must become visible after the user has clicked one by one another group of entities. I’ve a system that allowed me to hide every element of this first series, but I cant figured out how to show the second series, mostly because the user could click the first series in any order. 
I’ve been trying to adapt this idea: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/, but It seems that the “visibililty” attribute does not work in A-Frame. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendered elements are not `DOM` elements, so CSS will have no effect here. To toggle the visibility, use `setAttribute()`

```
someElement.setAttribute('visible', false) // or true
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0o2md83u/). Docs [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/visible.html#sidebar).

Comment: Thank you, @Piotr Adam Milewski. I understand your point, but I think I did not make myself clear: taking your fiddle into account, could it be possible that the visible true/ visible false function would be triggered not by click in one sphere but a series of two or three spheres, and only when all of them, in no particular order, has been clicked? 
I hope the question is clearer now. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Exactly. You are amazing. Thank you!